# Is FindFirstChangeNotification API doing any disk access?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-ce

I am using **[FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** / **[FindNextChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** / **[FindCloseChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** functions, and I am wondering if they are accessing to the disk or if they are just doing memory access ?

Especially :
*When FindNextChangeNotification is executed, the recorded change immediately satisfies a wait for the change notification.*
Where changes are recorded ?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your code not work? Please provide some more information about what you are doing and what your problem is.
It doesn't matter how and where the changes are recorded. This is implementation detail and not a behavior you can rely on.

Comment: The code is working fine, but I just want to clarify how these functions behave in windows CE regarding disk access (which are very slow in my context).

Comment: Same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19260398/17034).  The language doesn't matter so same answer.

Comment: @HansPassant If it is a duplicate why didn't you mark it as such?

Comment: Because I get endlessly harassed by C++ users that hate C#, it isn't worth it.